# Ionic native storage : storage.getItem() does not work

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, cordova-nativestorage

I am using ionic native storage to store some data. When i store and retrieve the data using `setItem()` and `getItem()` it works perfectly. But when i assign a value retrieved by `getItem()` in `then` block. it does not work outside the block.

```js
showDetails(name: string) {
    this.stg.getItem(name).then(data => {
      console.log(data);
      
      this.pathName = data.name;
      this.type = data.type;
      this.positions = JSON.parse(data.positions);
      
      console.log(this.positions);
      
    });

    console.log(this.pathName + " " + this.type);
  }
```

When i print the data in the console i got the result and also i got the result when i print a single value inside `then` block but the last `console.log` shows to me undefined undefined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears as though `getItem` returns a Promise as can be seen in the [documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/enterprise/nativestorage). This means that `this.pathName` will only be set in the callback you are providing to `then`. If this is asynchronous then by the time your undefined line is run the `then` callback has not been called and thus no value has been set. This is one of the gotchas to async programming.

A better approach would be to put all of your logic inside the callback:

```
showDetails(name: string) {
    // get item could be async so do not assume your callback will be run immediately
    this.stg.getItem(name).then(data => {
      console.log(data);

      this.pathName = data.name;
      this.type = data.type;
      this.positions = JSON.parse(data.positions);

      console.log(this.positions);

      // values now been set
      console.log(this.pathName + " " + this.type);
    });

    // at this point no values have been set as the callback has not been called
    console.log(this.pathName + " " + this.type); // so this line is undefined
  }
```

Comment: This works but only inside then. When i am trying to return the value or using it outside `then` it has an undefined value.

Comment: This question has been marked as duplicate and some other questions with similar issues have been provided. I'd recommend checking out this thorough [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23667087/1742518) for a similar question. ?Understanding this is a difficult but important step.